# Jackson Json View for Deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Json object coming back with the same property with different purposes based on the request (the resulting Json is out of my control).  I only care about the property value when I make a specific request.  Is there any way to use views for deserialization or something else that will conditionally propagate the pojo?

Example:
Json

```
"boo":
{
  "a": "foo"
}

"boo":
{
  "a": { "x": 3 }
}
```

Java

```
public class Views {
  public static class WhatIWant {}
  public static class SomeOtherThings {}
}

public class Result {
  @JsonView(View.WhatIWant)
  public string a;
}

Result r = mapper.getDeserializationConfig()
                 .setDeserializationView(Views.WhatIWant.class)??
                 .readValue(node, Result.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Jackson, [JSON Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) are for serialization only.

To deserialize JSON data into sometimes a String and other times an object would require [custom deserialization processing](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers).

Answer (score 6):

As of Jackson 2.0, [JSONViews are available for deserialization too](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews).